# Shorcut in NetBeans or Eclipse for currency symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

In Java, I can display currency in decimal format with currency symbol `¤`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

In NetBeans and Eclipse, how to type this  `¤` symbol.  Actually in this question I do copy and paste.

Comment: What currency is that?  It looks like a square on my system (Fedora 15 and Chrome).

Comment: That is considered a generic currency symbol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_(typography)

Answer (score 1):

To type a character like `¤` you would hold the `Alt` key down and type `0164` (tested on Windows).

In Windows you can see the Character Map by clicking the `Start` button and navigating to the `Accessories` folder where you will find a `System Tools` folder which contains the Character Map application.

On a Gnome system it is located in the `Applications > Accessories > Character Map` menu item

**NetBeans Shortcut**

One way to do this in NetBeans is to create a `Code Template` that will handle the expansion for you.  To do this, click `Tools > Options > Editor > Code Templates` and create a new template with the `¤` character as the `Expanded Text`.  Then you can use whatever `Abbreviation` that you defined for the `Code Template` and press the `TAB` button to expand it.

For example, I defined a new `Code Template` that used the `Abbreviation` of `gc` for the generic currency symbol.  Now when I type `gc` and press `TAB` in the editor, it gets expanded to `¤`.

**Eclipse Shortcut**

To create a `Code Template` in Eclipse, go to the Preferences panel through `Window > Preferences` and expand the `Java > Editor > Templates` section.  Once there, click the `New..` button and fill out the `Name`, select a `Context` that the template will be available in and in the `Pattern` text area type the `¤` symbol.

To expand the template in whichever `Context` you chose, type (for example) `gc` and then use the `Control + Space` combination to expand the template.  If other similar values map to the letters you've chosen then the code completion list will appear and you will need to select your template from the list.

Answer (score 1):

On personal computers running the Microsoft Windows or DOS operating systems, additional characters to those available in the current keyboard layout can be typed using an `Alt code`: pressing and holding the Alt key while entering a character code with the keyboard's numeric keypad.

Often this is the best or only method many computer users know for entering non-ASCII characters.

You might want to see this : [ALT CODES REFERENCE SHEET](http://usefulshortcuts.com/downloads/ALT-Codes.pdf) (This contains your `¤` and many more)